# AWS: Is it good practice to have webapp and DB instance in same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am too new to the cloud and AWS. I am working on some web application where I need to store some data on RDS.
In AWS cloud I am using `Beanstalk` for deploying my java code and `MySQL` as DB via `AWS-RDS`.

My question is - Is it a good practice to have `beanstalk [EC2]` and `RDS` instance inside a same `VPC`?
P.S: In [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html) link the scenario is explained as possible, but I want to know what would be the best practice.

Comment: Best practice is for the RDS instance to be multi-AZ, in private subnets, without a public IP, and reachable only by those systems that need access (typically inbound security group will only allow access from your app servers). Whether or not the app and the DB should be in the same VPC depends entirely on your architecture (e.g. you may have multiple apps all connecting to the same DB) but, in general, most deployments have the RDS instance in the same VPC as the app, otherwise you introduce complexities such as VPC peering or VPN between VPCs.

Comment: @jarmod, Thanks for the clear explanation. I think, this could be an answer rather than comment :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best practice is for the RDS instance to be multi-AZ, in private subnets, without a public IP, and reachable only by those systems that need access (typically the RDS instance's inbound security group will only allow access from the app servers).

Whether or not the app and the DB should be in the same VPC depends entirely on your architecture (e.g. you may have multiple apps all connecting to the same DB) but, in general, most deployments have the RDS instance in the same VPC as the app, typically in different subnets, otherwise you introduce complexities such as VPC peering or VPN between VPCs.

Answer (score 3):

Your VPC is your private network. It is definitely best practice to have both the web servers and the database servers inside the same private network.